# Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist... Seeder not working in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I would like to put some data in table so I would like to use DatabaseSeeder but when I try : php artisan db:seed this error occur:

```
ReflectionException  : Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist

  at /home/bruno/projetconcert/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:767
    763|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
    764|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    765|         }
    766| 
  `enter code here`> 767|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
```

I have already try to do a composer dump-autoload or changing namespace or use another directory in "autoload" in  composer.json but nothing work...

here the 2 files :

```
 <?php

    namespace database\seeds;
    namespace projetconcert;

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {

            $this->call(CategoryPlaceSeeder::class);

        }
    }
```

the second one :

```
<?php


namespace database\seeds;
namespace projetconcert;


use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use DB;

class CategoryPlaceSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('category_places')->insert([

                                            [
                                                'id' => 1,
                                                'category_name' => 'balcon',
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'id' => 2,
                                                'category_name' => 'terasse',
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'id' => 3,
                                                'category_name' => 'debout',
                                            ],
                                        ]);
    }
}
```

If someone have any idea, it would help for my project. Thanks

Comment: Your namespaces are wrong. Why do you have namespace declared 2 times anyway?

Comment: ok, what should I can keep and remove ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
namespace database\seeds;
namespace projetconcert;
```

from those files.

Btw you can define multiple namespaces per file but it is not recommended and this is not how or why you would do it. See here for more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

Comment: See edit you should remove both namespaces. Did you move the DatabaseSeeder.php file? It should be in `/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`

Comment: Now it works !! I remove both namespaces. Thks a lot :-)